# returning pointer to pointer array of a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am working on a C program that holds an array of pointer to structs.
First the struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int ID;
    char Name [20];
} rec;
```

Then I have a function that creates 1 of these structs:

```
struct rec* addEntry(){
    rec *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(rec));
    printf("Please give me an ID number\n");
    scanf("%d", &temp->ID);

    printf("Now give me a name, maximum size for this is 20 characters\n");
    scanf("%s", &temp->Name);
    return temp;
}
```

Now this function works fine, it creates the struct and returns the pointer towards that struct
I then have another function that creates a pointer array and fills it with pointers towards the structs:

```
struct rec* returnPointerToPointerArray()
{
    rec *pointerArray[2];
    pointerArray[0] = addEntry();
    pointerArray[1] = addEntry();
    printf("ID in main : %d\n", pointerArray[0]->ID);
    printf("Name in main : %s\n", pointerArray[0]->Name);
    printf("ID in main : %d\n", pointerArray[1]->ID);
    printf("Name in main : %s\n", pointerArray[1]->Name);
    pointerArray = malloc(sizeof(rec*)*2);
    return pointerArray;
}
```

For checking what happens I print the values that are stored at the places in the pointer array.
At this point the values in the pointer array are correct.

However now I need to malloc room for this pointerArray and return a pointer to this pointer array, and that is where I get stuck.

The malloc line gives me an error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct rec *[(sizetype)(size)]' from type 'void *'
```

Now to clarify I cannot use a linked list, I have to use an array of pointers instead.
To add in my main loop I have another error in the following bit of code:

```
rec *pointerArray[2];
pointerArray = returnPointerToPointerArray(2);
printf("ID in main : %d\n", pointerArray[0]->ID);
printf("Name in main : %s\n", pointerArray[0]->Name);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct rec *[2]' from type 'struct rec *'
```

Any help is more then welcome.

Thanks in advance, Ylva

Comment: 'pointerArray = malloc(sizeof(rec*)*2);' will not work and is anyway too late for what you intended since you already tried to store stuff in it.  'pointerArray' is an automatic-storage array, not a pointer, so you cannot malloc it.

Comment: But if I would return a pointer to that array would then the array not be gone since it is declared locally?

Comment: You have created pointers to struct in both functions without initializing them to point anywhere before using them.   I wrote example below (had errors when first written, they have been tested now)

Comment: How nice of you to tell the user exactly how to exploit your buffer overflow.

Comment: `struct rec` is not defined anywhere. If you write `struct rec *` then that defines a new type, which is incompatible with `rec` .

Comment: Arrays are rvalues in C, so you cannot assign into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't make sense:

```
struct rec* returnPointerToPointerArray()
{
    rec *pointerArray[2];
    pointerArray[0] = addEntry();
    pointerArray[1] = addEntry();
    ...
    pointerArray = malloc(sizeof(rec*)*2);
    return pointerArray;
}
```

you're defining a stack array of pointers and assigning heap addresses for `struct rec` objects to them and afterwards trying to assign a heap-based array of two pointers to the address of the stack one. It will never compile.

Since your function is designed to return a pointer to an object of `rec` type (which will be the first of the two structures in the array I guess), you should first allocate on the heap the space for the two pointers (and thus use a double pointer) and then populate it/return it:

```
struct rec** returnPointerToPointerArray()
{
    rec **pointerArray;
    pointerArray = malloc(sizeof(rec*)*2); // Allocates 2 pointers
    pointerArray[0] = addEntry();
    pointerArray[1] = addEntry();
    ...
    return pointerArray;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/PnNuw8)</kbd>

You should also free the allocated memory when you're done.

Comment: At last, that looks more like it.

Comment: `struct rec` and `rec` are different types, and you only return a pointer to **one** of the entries.

Comment: @MattMcNabb That's correct too, sorry. I hadn't checked the return type in the first place. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

two problems here i identified:

First, you return before you copy the result to `pointerArray`.

```
pointerArray = malloc(sizeof(rec*)*2);
return pointerArray;
```

my suggestion is

```
struct rec** returnPointerToPointerArray()
{
    rec *pointerArray[2];
    pointerArray[0] = addEntry();
    pointerArray[1] = addEntry();
    printf("ID in main : %d\n", pointerArray[0]->ID);
    printf("Name in main : %s\n", pointerArray[0]->Name);
    printf("ID in main : %d\n", pointerArray[1]->ID);
    printf("Name in main : %s\n", pointerArray[1]->Name);
    rec **pointerArray2 = malloc(sizeof pointerArray);
    pointerArray2[0] = pointerArray[0];
    pointerArray2[1] = pointerArray[1];
    return pointerArray2;
}
```

notice that i have changed the variable name. you did make some other mistakes in your code.

Second,

```
rec *pointerArray[2];
```

is an array of pointer. the way to declare it is simply:

```
rec **pointerArray;
```

btw,

```
pointerArray = returnPointerToPointerArray(2);
```

this line should make the usage and declaration mismatch.

UPDATE:

found some error in my answer. you are returning an array of pointers.

Comment: would rec *pointerArray; not just create a pointer to a type rec? and not be an array of pointers to type rec?

Comment: @Ylva don't understand what you are worrying about. pointer and array are identical in typing system. `rec *pointerArray;` is a pointer pointing to some address. dereferencing it as an array by `pointerArray[1]` or so.

Comment: pointerArray = returnPointerToPointerArray(2); will indeed not work, should be pointerArray = returnPointerToPointerArray();

Comment: Yes, it would do exactly that, which is not what you need.

Comment: Okay I tried to change the code to rec *pointerArray; this however gives an error which states incomaptible types when assigning to type rec from type struct rec * at the lines where I add 2 entries

Comment: @Ylva yup, i did make mistakes. updated already. you should use double pointer since you want to point to an array.

Comment: Looking at the answer below you where nearly correct, I indeed did not have to use rec *pointerArray[2]; however I had to use rec **pointerArray;

Comment: @Ylva: Note that answers can move around as votes are cast and acceptance changed. It is better to refer to the answer by the name of the author.

Comment: @Nisse Thank you for warning me for this.

Comment: To clarify with the answer I meant the post from @Marco

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct
{
    int ID;
    char Name [20];
} rec;

struct rec* returnPointerToPointerArray()
{
    rec *pointerArray[2];
    pointerArray[0] = addEntry();
    pointerArray[1] = addEntry();
    ...
    return pointerArray;
}
```

The return type is wrong for two reasons. The function returns a `rec *`, while it is declared to return a pointer to an undefined `struct rec *`. The type `struct rec` is not the same as the typedef `rec`!

Secondly, you should return a **pointer to pointer** to `rec`. When you return the array, the array name is converted to a pointer to its first element, which itself is a pointer.

Also, you have declared `pointerArray` as an actual array. You can not assign a new value to an array, and you can not return a pointer to a local variable. The lifetime of `pointerArray` ends when execution leaves this function, so a pointer to it will be entirely useless. Using such a pointer results in *undefined behaviour*.

You need to **first** allocate dynamic memory for the array, populate the array, and then return it:

```
rec** returnPointerToPointerArray()
{
  rec **pA = malloc (2 * sizeof *pA);
  if (pA) {
    pA[0] = addEntry();
    pA[1] = addEntry();
    if (pA[0]) {
      printf("ID in main : %d\n", pA[0]->ID);
      printf("Name in main : %s\n", pA[0]->Name);
    }
    if (pA[1]) {
      printf("ID in main : %d\n", pA[1]->ID);
      printf("Name in main : %s\n", pA[1]->Name);
    }
  }
  return pA;
}
```

Same problem here:

```
rec *pointerArray[2];
pointerArray = returnPointerToPointerArray(2);
printf("ID in main : %d\n", pointerArray[0]->ID);
printf("Name in main : %s\n", pointerArray[0]->Name);
```

You can not assign a new value to an array. You need to define `pointerArray` as a **pointer to pointer**:

```
rec **pointerArray;
pointerArray = returnPointerToPointerArray(/*2*/);
```