# return dynamic array of struct from function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

How do I dynamically create an array of struct in a function in C?

The struct:

```
typedef struct Track {
    char artist[LONGSTR];
    char file[LONGSTR];
    int id;
    int isAlbum;
    char name[LONGSTR];
    int pos;
    char title[LONGSTR];
    int time;
} Track;
```

The function:

```
int
processplaylist (struct Track** tracks, char* resp)
{
  //count the tracks to return
  //allocate space for the resulting tracks

  *tracks = mem_alloc (count * sizeof (struct Track));

  //process each track
  return count;
}
```

And the usage:

```
char playliststr[] = "file: some-mp3\nTitle: Dire Straits - Romeo And Juliet\nName: TheRadio\nPos: 0\nId: 12\nOK\n"
struct Track* tracks = NULL;
int count = mpd_processplaylist(&tracks, playliststr);
```

Within the function the tracks are nicely processed and upto the return statement tracks points to the right location to get to the tracks. Most questions I have seen are about arrays to values, not structs.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26720944/1721216) returns an array of structs, but I would like to return the count (question of style) and return the array through the parameter.

What is going wrong? After the function returns, count has the right value and tracks is still NULL.

Comment: sounds a piece of homework. is that `mem_alloc` function provided?

Comment: `processplaylist` implies processing the `resp` on the go so your `Track` array needs to double its size if not long enough. given the `mem_alloc` function provided, what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Not homework, that has been a while. mem_alloc() is a counting memory allocation function, not much more than malloc(); memset(); memcount++;

Comment: Assuming `mem_alloc` works like `malloc`, your code looks OK to me. Did you have a question?

Comment: @Albert so what exactly is your question, since that function call has answered your question.

Comment: 1) Check the value of `count` _right before_ `mem_alloc`, 2) check the return value of `mem_alloc`, 3) replace `mem_alloc` with `malloc`.

Comment: On the face of it, the code you show should work.  Since you assert that it does not work, there is room to think that the problem is in code that you don't show.  Please create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that demonstrates the problem.  It doesn't need to find the actual playlist; it just needs to put some data in place and demonstrate the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Have you tried finding the problem yourself with a debugger? Seems like a pretty straightforward problem to debug without needing to turn to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the not so nice people pointed out by down voting the question, the question is too broad and vague. I apologize for that, I was desperate.

As the nice people in the comments confirmed, the code is correct. Even though the debugger showed that just before the return statement everything was OK and after returning to the usage it was not.

By commenting out code lines and logging a lot, there are two things to note.
Within the function, you must refer to the individual tracks as `(*tracks + i)` or, for example, `(*(*tracks + i)).file`. Indeed, not shown in the sample code. I had tried `*(tracks + i)`, `&tracks[i]` and `tracks + i`, which in the debugger all seemed to work and did not cause *immediate* errors. I guess the code messed up memory that only came out after the return.

Outside the function, in the usage, you refer to the tracks as an array, as `tracks[i]` or, for example, `tracks[i].file`.

I hope that at least my answer helps.

Comment: Are you sure about `(*tracks + i).file` ? `tracks` being a `struct Track**`, you'd be trying to apply `.` on a `struct Track*`. In any case, this looks like the operator precedence issue with pointers-to-arrays, where you need to write `(*arr)[i]` rather than `*arr[i]`.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for pointing that out. While debugging it shows correct, but in reality it is not.